# I dont know why this code does not add li element

Tags: javascript

In console, am getting undefined, but I can't understand.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djamali/eyzjv2jo/)

```js
function createItem(element) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = element.value;
  var ul = document.getElementById('todo');
  ul.appendChild(li);

}
var element = document.getElementById("input")
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = createItem;
console.log(element);
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>todo List</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="todo_root">
    <form id="form">
    <ul id="todo">
        <li><input type="text" id="input"><button id="submit">Добавить</button></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments. Edit your question. **What** line/variable is undefined?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your html :)

Comment: i have this https://jsfiddle.net/djamali/eyzjv2jo/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle, the form is being submitted, in order to prevent that in the below code I have used the event.preventDefault, and then you need to pass the element parameter to the createItem function.

```
function createItem(element) {
    var li=document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText=element.value;
    var ul=document.getElementById('todo');
    ul.appendChild(li);

}

var element = document.getElementById("input");
document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function(e){
  event.preventDefault();
  createItem(element);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :)

```js
function createItem(element) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var ul = document.getElementById('todo');
  ul.appendChild(li);

}
var element = document.getElementById("input")
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = createItem;
console.log(element);
```

```html
<ul id="todo">
</ul>


<input id="input" >? </input>

<button id="submit" />
```

Comment: Is the submit button `<button id="submit" />` rendered yet? try putting the link to the javascript at the bottom of your html file

Comment: its add undefined

Comment: make sure the input box `<input id="input" >? </input>` is rendered and `li.innerText = document.getElementById("input").value;` gets the value from it

Comment: this work <button id="submit" onclick="createItem()">Добавить</button>

Comment: Great! Make sure to mark the question as answered :)

Comment: i dont know how this do